# How can I check email validation in cypress

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

I want to check validation for input element. Can I check if typing wrong or valid Email format in my input.
Like this.

```
 cy.get('#email_signup').type(validateEmail())
         var email = "";
            var possible = "abcd@.gh";
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            email += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
            return email;
        }

        cy.get('.nextBtn').click();
        cy.get('.error-message').should('be.visible');
```

Comment: What is your purpose? Do you want to validate if error message is displayed or just want to validate if you have inserted correct format? I can't understand what you want to do from the code?

Comment: I want to check, if pasted valid email or not. If pasted wrong format should be shown error message. if pasted right format email, error message should not be visible.

Comment: Why do you try to do a random email generation? don't you think you'll lose some scenarios? And after cy.get('#email_signup').type(validate email()) line your steps are not clear. Have you mistakenly added the steps of the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what you expect to do, you need two external functions to create emails and to get a valid state of emails. Then you need to loop the **it** hook throughout all the emails.

```
//Create Emails
//Did a small modification so that you can decied the email length you need
const emails = (val) => {
var email = "";
var possible = "abcd@.gh";
for (var i = 0; i < val; i++){
email += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));}
return email;
}


//validate emails
//I have used a general Regex here, use the regex you have used in your website insted

const validateEmail = (email) => {
var re = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
return re.test(email);
}

//Test Cases (I have added 10 loops so it will create 10 test cases)
//Change the test case count as much as you need
for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
const TestEmail = emails(10)
const EmailState = validateEmail(TestEmail)
it("EmailTest -"+ TestEmail +" - " + EmailState,() => {
cy.get('#email_signup').type(TestEmail)
cy.get('.nextBtn').click();
    if(!EmailState){
         cy.get('.error-message').should('be.visible');
    }else{
         cy.get('.error-message').should('not.be.visible');
    }
})
}
```

Your method of creating emails is awesome. But make sure you add a separate test to check specific and valid scenarios as random emails might not cover them all

This is how the tests are going to look like.

[image]

Note: As I have mentioned earlier. It's always better to know your test data. So Without a random generation. Try to have a list of valid, invalid email scenarios with true false conditions And loop through them.

Answer (score 2):

First of all it's good to generate random emails, but the best way to do is have a set of emails in a array. (may be in a JSON) and loop through them and check for the email validity.

Eg:

```
{
"Email_1":"['robot@mail.com','valid']",
"Email_2":"['robotmail.com','InValid']",
}
```

Because then you know the email conditions you are testing. But if you want to go with a random email generation method. I totally agree with the Muditha Perera's answer. It works perfectly.