# How to Include a piece of Js code or Js file for Email Format Validation in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, email-validation, email-formats

Update/Edit: I have a fixture file which contains firstname, lastname and email and it loops through `beforeeach()` and enters them in the respective fields. The verification i want to do is lets say a bad email is entered without '@','.com' or just '@' present or just '.com' these should fail when the field is verified.

```
const availablefixtures = [
{
    "name": "data3",
    "context": "1"
},
{
    "name": "data2",
    "context": "2"
}
]
```

data from fixture file is:

```
{
    "firstname": "Lambda",
    "lastname": "Jonas",
    "email": "ljonas@example.com"
}

describe('demoniftyhappysuite', function () {
//loop through both the fixtues 
availablefixtures.forEach((afixture) => {
    describe(afixture.context, () => {
enter code here

cy.fixture(afixture.name).then(function (data) {
                this.data = data;
            })
```

Currently i am reading the email value from a data file in fixtures

```
it('demoniftyhappytest', {}, function () {
cy.get('input[name="personal.email"]').type(this.data.email, { 
log: false 
}).invoke('val').should('not.be.empty')
```

**From: [How can I check email validation in cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62953993/how-can-i-check-email-validation-in-cypress)**
the best way to do is have a set of emails in a array. (may be in a JSON) and loop through them and check for the email validity.

Eg:

```
{
"Email_1":"['robot@mail.com','valid']",
"Email_2":"['robotmail.com','InValid']",
}
```

**Second Solution: Example**
Try the following code for email validation.

```
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    <!--
     function validateEmail() {
     var emailID = document.myForm.EMail.value;
     atpos = emailID.indexOf("@");
     dotpos = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");
     
     if (atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 )) {
        alert("Please enter correct email ID")
        document.myForm.EMail.focus() ;
        return false;
     }
     return( true );
     }
    //-->
    </script>
```

I want it to be something simple like even if it verifies @symbol and .com in the email entered for time being.

Comment: What state does the field have if the value is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `.forEach()` to iterate through the array of emails and determine the behavior that way. As you've currently constructed your email json, we'll need to get the array from `Object.values()`.

```js
const emails = {
  "Email_1": ['robot@mail.com','valid'],
  "Email_2": ['robotmail.com','InValid'],
}

describe('tests', () => {
  it('validates the emails', () => {
    Object.values(emails).forEach((value) => {
      if (value[1] === 'valid') {
        // code to run if valid -- reference email address as `value[0]`
      } else if (value[1] === 'InValid') {
        // code to run if invalid -- reference email address as `value[0]
      }
    });
  });
});
```

If you wanted to change your object to be an array of arrays, it would be something like this:

```js
const emails = [ ['foo@gmail.com', 'valid'], ['foogmail.com', 'InValid'] ];
...
emails.forEach((email) => {
  if (email[1] === 'valid') {
    ...
  } else if (email[1] === 'InValid') {
    ...
  }
// reference email value as `email[0]`
})
```

Or if you wanted to make it an array of objects

```js
const emails = [ { email: 'foo@gmail.com', isValid: true }, { email: 'foogmail.com', isValid: false } ];
emails.forEach((value) => {
  if (value.isValid) {
   ...
  } else {
   ...
  }
})
// email address is referenced by `value.email`
```

Comment: I am going to experiment with the first solution u mentioned and see if it can check for a valid gmail and normal email address passed through fixtures. But also another problem i observed is the field on the form is not validating email, its taking anything except for empty. So what i was trying to do was lets say i enter kill@gmail.com it should say its valid or if i enter killgmail it should throw a error or we should assert for that?? Is that something achievable?

Comment: You can check the invalid error state by going into the `else if` block and validating there. Because _you_ control the data, you know what the expectation is.

Comment: So i am lost looks like because, i have fixtures which are reading for firstname, lastname and email and going through a loop in before each and everytime its picking up the values from fixtures and filling the form.

I am unable to use the above mentioned solution as email is already being pulled from the fixture, is there any way after the email is typed in the box to verify the format??

Comment: Can you edit your original post with what your data actually looks like, and what your test for an invalid field would look like? The pseudo-code provided obviously isn't working or isn't providing a clear enough example of how to implement this. The tl;dr is that the validation should go in the `else if` block. How you determine an email as valid or invalid is up to you, but you need _something_ to tell the code to validate the error states.

Comment: the above is one of the fixture files which has the data and it gets entered into the form while it runs through beforeach, so when a invalid email is entered on the field, is there any way to verify , because it will fill the invalid email and when it clicks continue there is a error message on the page saying invalid email/Please enter a valid domain

Comment: Yes, but you need to provide a way to know if it is an invalid email or not. The logic you use can be in the `beforeEach()` block, but you have to tell Cypress what to do.

Comment: Or are you asking, more generally, how you can validate if an email is valid before it even tries to type in the invalid email?

Comment: More like once the email is entered need to validate if its valid or not(if its wrong the page throws error) and i tried updating the post like you mentioned earlier

Comment: Currently i am just making sure the field is not empty, havent done any validation and not sure how to do it